# Elegant grouping of implicit value classes

Tags: scala, value-class, implicit-class

I'm writing a set of implicit *Scala* wrapper classes for an existing *Java* library (so that I can *decorate* that library to make it more convenient for *Scala* developers).

As a trivial example, let's say that the *Java* library (which I can't modify) has a class such as the following:

```
public class Value<T> {
    // Etc.
    public void setValue(T newValue) {...}
    public T getValue() {...}
}
```

Now let's say I want to decorate this class with *Scala*-style getters and setters. I can do this with the following implicit class:

```
final implicit class RichValue[T](private val v: Value[T])
extends AnyVal {
  // Etc.
  def value: T = v.getValue
  def value_=(newValue: T): Unit = v.setValue(newValue)
}
```

The `implicit` keyword tells the *Scala* compiler that it can convert instances of `Value` to be instances of `RichValue` implicitly (provided that the latter is in scope). So now I can apply methods defined within `RichValue` to instances of `Value`. For example:

```
def increment(v: Value[Int]): Unit = {
  v.value = v.value + 1
}
```

(Agreed, this isn't very nice code, and is not exactly *functional*. I'm just trying to demonstrate a simple use case.)

Unfortunately, *Scala* does not allow `implicit` classes to be top-level, so they must be defined within a `package object`, `object`, `class` or `trait` and not just in a `package`. (I have no idea why this restriction is necessary, but I assume it's for compatibility with *implicit conversion functions*.)

However, I'm also extending `RichValue` from `AnyVal` to make this a *value class*. If you're not familiar with them, they allow the *Scala* compiler to make allocation optimizations. Specifically, the compiler does not always need to create instances of `RichValue`, and can operate directly on the *value class*'s constructor argument.

In other words, there's very little performance overhead from using a *Scala implicit value class* as a wrapper, which is nice. :-)

However, a major restriction of *value classes* is that they cannot be defined within a `class` or a `trait`; they can only be members of `package`s, `package object`s or `object`s. (This is so that they do not need to maintain a pointer to the outer class instance.)

An *implicit value class* must honor both sets of constraints, so it can only be defined within a `package object` or an `object`.

And therein lies the problem. The library I'm wrapping contains a deep hierarchy of packages with a huge number of classes and interfaces. Ideally, I want to be able to import my wrapper classes with a single `import` statement, such as:

```
import mylib.implicits._
```

to make using them as simple as possible.

The only way I can currently see of achieving this is to put all of my *implicit value class* definitions inside a single `package object` (or `object`) within a single source file:

```
package mylib
package object implicits {

  implicit final class RichValue[T](private val v: Value[T])
  extends AnyVal {
    // ...
  }

  // Etc. with hundreds of other such classes.
}
```

However, that's far from ideal, and I would prefer to mirror the package structure of the target library, yet still bring everything into scope via a single `import` statement.

Is there a straightforward way of achieving this that doesn't sacrifice any of the benefits of this approach?

(For example, I know that if I forego making these wrappers *value classes*, then I can define them within a number of different `trait`s - one for each component package - and have my root `package object` extend all of them, bringing everything into scope through a single import, but I don't want to sacrifice performance for convenience.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
implicit final class RichValue[T](private val v: Value[T]) extends AnyVal
```

Is essentially a syntax sugar for the following two definitions

```
import scala.language.implicitConversions // or use a compiler flag

final class RichValue[T](private val v: Value[T]) extends AnyVal
@inline implicit def RichValue[T](v: Value[T]): RichValue[T] = new RichValue(v)
```

(which, you might see, is why implicit classes have to be inside traits, objects or classes: they also have matching `def`)

There is nothing that requires those two definitions to live together. You can put them into separate objects:

```
object wrappedLibValues {
  final class RichValue[T](private val v: Value[T]) extends AnyVal {
    // lots of implementation code here
  }
}

object implicits {
  @inline implicit def RichValue[T](v: Value[T]): wrappedLibValues.RichValue[T] = new wrappedLibValues.RichValue(v)
}
```

Or into traits:

```
object wrappedLibValues {
  final class RichValue[T](private val v: Value[T]) extends AnyVal {
    // implementation here
  }

  trait Conversions {
    @inline implicit def RichValue[T](v: Value[T]): RichValue[T] = new RichValue(v)
  }
}

object implicits extends wrappedLibValues.Conversions
```

Comment: I'm not sure that this is as convenient as I was hoping for. :-) According to [SIP-13 (implicit classes)](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/implicit-classes.html), the implicit conversion function isn't `@inline`d automatically - where do you get that from? Also, by explicitly creating a instance of the wrapper class - even if `@inline`d - do you still get the performance benefit? [SIP-15 (value classes)](http://docs.scala-lang.org/sips/completed/value-classes.html) suggests not. I guess some benchmarking might be in order...

Comment: @MikeAllen yeah, I was wrong on inlining (tho it does not hurt). And yes, by explicitly creating an instance you still get the benefit. E.g. [here](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Tj7W6WVHQR6DJpz26QwC2w) with `-Xprint:jvm` compiler option you can see the call transformed to `Foo.printInt$extension`

Comment: OK, I guess that makes sense. I'm accepting your answer, but - in truth - I no longer technically have _implicit value classes_, but _implicit conversion functions_ and _value classes_, so the solution for each wrapper is far more verbose and, potentially, error prone. :-( But, at least I can organize my code better. :-) I guess a better solution, building on this, would be to use a macro to expand class declarations...